# Filtering eclipse's project explorer view from library entries

Tags: eclipse, scala-ide

How can I remove those lines shaded in blue? 
Working with multiple open projects in eclipse becomes a nightmare with this verbosity... it is very hard to navigate between the projects' sources with this excessive screen estate.

[image]

Comment: Which Eclipse view is that? Project Explorer? Package Explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a configuration option to hide them in **Project Explorer**, unfortunately. But if you use **Package Explorer** you can filter those out (plus, they're grouped under the **Referenced Libraries** node so they're easily collapsible).

Comment: Indeed, the package explorer is a bit better.